# Android studio gradle custom task with shell script is not working at build time

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, sh

I have encrypted a file(API key,passwords etc), added in codebase. I need to add a custom task(task encIt) to decrypt the file(will call decrypt.sh to decrypt).This task is added in build.gradle file.

I have tested this by calling "**gradle encIt**" from terminal and it works fine(decrypting the file as expected), But I need this to be happened every time I build the gradle; how to do that?

This is the task:

```
     task encIt(type:Exec) {
       println("WORKING")
       commandLine "./decrypt.sh"
       println("WORKING")
     }
```

This is the script file :

```
   #!/usr/bin/env sh
   echo "inside working"
   openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -d  -in ../encrypted.key   -out  key.txt                     -pass pass:Abcdk5551
  echo "inside working"
```

I have tested this

senario 1:gradle encIt

```
 result : WORKING
          inside working
          inside working
          WORKING
   The file is decrypted
```

senario 1:gradle/gradlew (no arguments)

```
 result : WORKING
          WORKING
   The file is not getting decrypted
```

please help!

using gradle version 5.4.1 
macbook pro
android studio 3.4.1

Answer (score 2):

edit`app/build.gradle`,add below code

```
task encIt(type:Exec) {
    println("WORKING")
    commandLine "./decrypt.sh"
    println("WORKING")
}

afterEvaluate {
    assembleDebug.dependsOn encIt
    assembleRelease.dependsOn encIt
}
```

It's worked with:

1. click `run` button which on Android Studio
2. run `./gradlew build`
3. run `./gradlew assemble`
4. run `./gradlew assembleDebug`
5. run `./gradlew assembleRelease`